# Google plus sdk linker error ios

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, google-plus

I am using google plus share sdk for posting to google plus. but it gives me following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kGTMOAuth2WebViewFailed", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch webView:didFailLoadWithError:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2WebViewKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch notifyWithName:webView:kind:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDomain", referenced from:
      -[GTLService objectFetcher:finishedWithData:error:] in GTLService.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connection:didReceiveData:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher isRetryError:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher shouldRetryNowForStatus:error:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication beginTokenFetchWithDelegate:didFinishSelector:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn handleCallbackReached] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
      ...
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherErrorChallengeKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeUserInfo", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn fetchGoogleUserInfo] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherStartedNotification", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher beginFetchMayDelay:mayAuthorize:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherRetryDelayStoppedNotification", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher destroyRetryTimer] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher failToBeginFetchWithError:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher backgroundFetchExpired] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeRefresh", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication beginTokenFetchWithDelegate:didFinishSelector:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2RefreshTokenChanged", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication setKeysForResponseDictionary:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2UserSignedIn", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn handleCallbackReached] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeToken", referenced from:
```

Please help me.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658205/googleplus-with-cocoapods-linking-error/19734379#19734379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to link `libGooglePlusUniversal.a` and the opensource "Google Toolbox for Mac files" into your project.

This can be done by either pressing `Project > Add to project` or dragging the files directly into your XCode project.