# GooglePlus with CocoaPods linking error

Tags: ios, google-plus, linker-errors, cocoapods

I added to my pod file

```
pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', '1.4.1'
```

I did a

```
pod update
```

I imported

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
```

But if i try to

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientID;
```

I get this error from linker:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPPSignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SDSocialManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: No problem if I add the lib directly in the project without cocoapods

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I tried changing `Build Active Architectures` to NO in both the Pod and Project Target to no avail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my experience linker errors typically don't lead to a "one solution fits all", but I was able to solve this problem myself by adding `${inherited}` to `Other Linker Flags` in Build Settings (Project Target).

Perhaps, by not having this tag, I wasn't inheriting some of the static libraries that were required by `GPPSignIn`.

Cheers!

Comment: @jsksma2 : Still don't work for me. I am not able to see ${inherited} beside the 'Other Linker Flags' even after adding it

Comment: Did not work for me either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758580/latest-google-plus-ios-sdk-1-7-1-not-supporting-architecture-x86-64