# Unable to load font: Roboto-Regular after updating to new Google+ SDK

Tags: google-plus

After updating to new Google+ sdk get an error NSBundle(GPP3PAdditions) gpp_registerFonts]_block_invoke() Unable to load font: Roboto-Regular

If someone got the same?
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add "GooglePlus.bundle" file to your project from Google iOS Sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is helpfull  thank you very much!!!
Also if anyone using CocoaPods please see here it also will help
[GooglePlus with CocoaPods linking error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658205/googleplus-with-cocoapods-linking-error)

add ${inherited}   to Other Linker Flags

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

Get the fonts from finder and copy files to your project. Then in your Info.plist file make changes like

[image: see this image]

After this click on build phases make sure you included font files(Roboto..) over there.

[image: for more clarity]

For more clarity check it..[How to include and use new fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

I hope it helps someone.