# Alternative to get current Cardboard head position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

I made update from Cardboard to GoogleVR so some code become deprecated.

I get the current head position of player to calculate the following user rotation. So what I need just to put player in front of image 
automatically. Here is an example:

moving player closer to picture

```
Vector3 spawnPos = hitObjectPos + hitObjectDirection * spawnDistance;
spawnPos = new Vector3 (spawnPos.x, transform.position.y, spawnPos.z);    
player.transform.position = spawnPos;
```

calculate rotation

```
var headRotation = Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Orientation;
Quaternion lookAt = Quaternion.LookRotation (hitObject.transform.position - transform.position);
```

perform rotate as need

```
Vector3 rot = new Vector3 (0, lookAt.eulerAngles.y - headRotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (rot);
```

But now `Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Orientation` is deprecated.
Does anyone find the alternative to find Head position?

Comment: Provided answer. It would be nice if you go back to your old questions and accept answers that solved your problems.Just click the check image. It will encourage others to answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26093080/3785314  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37690101/3785314 http://stackoverflow.com/a/37634914/3785314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is a new plugin update, please read the release note before updating. The [release note](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/release-notes) mentioned that many things has been renamed.

You are actually suppose to get `namespace` error instead of warning. This means that you did **NOT** install the update the recommended way. Please delete the old cardbaord directories as instructed then download and import everything in the `GoogleVRForUnity.unitypackage`.

It mentions that `Cardboard.SDK`, is now `GvrViewer.Instance`. So `Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Orientation` should now be `GvrViewer.Instance.HeadPose.Orientation;`

Comment: Thanks you, it helps!